# How to make fulltext search in PostgreSQL useful?

Tags: postgresql

I have a russian dictionary in postgresql 8.4.

I try to use full search but have some troubles.

1. I dont get any results becouse try to find words by 4-5symbols. For example:

   ```
   select * from parcels_temp where name_dispatcher @@ to_tsquery('Нику');
   ```

   Get result: 0 rows.

   ```
   select * from parcels_temp where name_dispatcher @@ to_tsquery('Никуд');
   ```

   Get result: 2 rows. its correct.
2. I try to do search by words not contained in dictionary. What i gonna do in this case? How can i update dictionary in PostgreSQL?
3. Its must create column to `tsvector` or i can use `to_tsvector` function i queries? Or its more slowly?

Answer (score 1):

1. Postgresql indexer does not process strings shorter than 3 characters. It is done to reduce index size and generation time.
2. Obviously, you get nothing. There is way to update dictionary, refer to documentation.
3. [Use GIN index on tsvector field](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch-indexes.html).

Comment: 1. I use 4-5 symbols. 2. Can you give a link to this docs. part?

Answer (score 0):

1: By default, postgreSQL only matches the whole word. You can opt in to do a prefix matching:

```
select * from parcels_temp where name_dispatcher @@ to_tsquery('Нику:*');
```

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-controls.html

3: You can create a column and GIN index on it, or you can just create the index without creating a column. I think they are the same in terms of performance. For details, see:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-tables.html